# Twitter Integration with Windows Phone 7 (GetRequestToken issue)

Tags: windows-phone-7, twitter

I want to integrate my Windows phone 7 Photo App with **Twitter**, but here is an issue, you please see the below code, the Red-Line below the **GetRequestToken** method. The twitter library is installed properly but still I am facing such problem, although on the Net articles, only this procedure is perfect. This is just a portion of code. Any one help please. I am using **VS2010** and **Windows Phone 7.1**.

[image: Figure]

Comment: Check once your library is must be working Titter API 1.1. Because Twitter API 1.0 has been retired recently.

Comment: The latest Libraries of both tweetsharp and hammock, both are installed. I am using VS2010 and Windows phone 7.1

Comment: @Zia Ur Rahman did u get the solution for this ???

Comment: No need to individually integrate the Twitter or Facebook or other social networks, Actually Windows Phone have its own ShareLinkTask class which can easily share the data on social networks in best manners.